# Box2d debug draw doesn't show sometimes, but bodies show as normal

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

Inside a subclass of CCLayer, there're two methods below:

```
-(void)setupDebugDraw 
{
    _debugDraw = new GLESDebugDraw(PTM_RATIO * [[CCDirector sharedDirector] contentScaleFactor]);
    world->SetDebugDraw(_debugDraw);

    uint32 flags = 0;
    flags += b2DebugDraw::e_shapeBit;
    flags += b2DebugDraw::e_jointBit;
    flags += b2DebugDraw::e_aabbBit;
    flags += b2DebugDraw::e_pairBit;
    flags += b2DebugDraw::e_centerOfMassBit;
    _debugDraw->SetFlags(flags);

    // (TEST CODE) BELOW DOESN'T SHOW!
    _debugDraw->DrawPoint(b2Vec2(0,0), 500.0f, b2Color(255, 255, 255));
}

-(void) draw {
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    if (world) {
        // BODIES SHOW OK
        world->DrawDebugData();

        // (TEST CODE) BELOW DOESN'T SHOW EITHER!
        _debugDraw->DrawPoint(b2Vec2(0,0), 500.0f, b2Color(255, 255, 255));
    }

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);    
}
```

In above code, there're two test codes, both doesn't show anything.

Xcode 4.3.2
IOS Simulator 5.1
Box2D 2.1.2

After some try:
_debugDraw->DrawPoint(b2Vec2(0,0), 50.0f, b2Color(255, 0, 0)); // NO DRAW
_debugDraw->DrawPoint(b2Vec2(1,1), 50.0f, b2Color(255, 0, 0)); // HAVE DRAW!!

seems draw point with one or more 0 will not draw at all! Even if the size is big enough!

```
void GLESDebugDraw::DrawPoint(const b2Vec2& p, float32 size, const b2Color& color)
{
    glColor4f(color.r, color.g, color.b,1);
    glPointSize(size);
    GLfloat             glVertices[] = {
        p.x * mRatio, p.y * mRatio
    };
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, glVertices);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);
    glPointSize(1.0f);
}
```

Since I don't understand the openGL api, anything susipcious here?

Comment: Btw, in case you're using cocos2d 2.0 this code won't work because the draw code is using OpenGL ES 1.1. Replace the Box2D debug draw class/code from the cocos2d 2.0 Box2D template.

Comment: Thx, but I use cocos2D 1.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

debug draw has an zindex of 0 so if your sprites have an zindex > 0 your will not see your debug draw.

Comment: I removed the background sprite, and the second test code draw a big enough area, so it should show when zorder is 0 too.

Comment: Not necessarily. Commands in draw method are drawn first, then the zOrder == 0 sprites are drawn, then the ones with zOrder > 0. Therefore if you want to see debug drawing info, draw it in a separate node that has a high zOrder or set the class' children to have a zOrder of -1 or less.

Comment: Found some clue, edited in question, seems the draw point problem.